# Get tweets from twitter app

Tags: android, twitter

I'm developing a social media hub for Android, which is planned to grab the tweets ect from the installed apps. The advantage of this should be that it doesn't need login on itself. the app will only combine all social media / messaging services for my custom rom.

My question was, how do i get the recent timeline from the user into my app (grabbing it from the twitter app on the phone)

Thanks in advance,
djpbx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to contact the authors of every Twitter client for Android and see if any of them offer an API that supports this. I suspect that none of them do, and hopefully they lack any security flaws that would allow script kiddies to get at this private information.

> I'm developing a social media hub for Android, which is planned to grab the tweets ect from the installed apps.

That will only work if the apps cooperate with you. Again, this is unlikely.

Comment: @djpbx There is nothing to set up. This is **not** possible, unless you cooperate with the creators of the apps.